# Dynamic HTML Table with XSLT

Tags: html, xslt-1.0

I need to loop over a group of values and print them into a two-column table.

I thought about following solution (must be xslt1)

```
<table class="main">

    <xsl:for-each select="Attribute/Gruppe">
        <xsl:if test="current()/@ID=20064490">
            <xsl:variable name="open_row"><![CDATA[<tr><td style="width:50%;">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name" /></td>]]></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="closing_row"><![CDATA[<td style="width:50%;">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name" /></td></tr>]]></xsl:variable>

            <xsl:variable name="table">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="(position() mod 2) = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$open_row"
                                disable-output-escaping="yes" />

                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>

                            <xsl:value-of select="$closing_row"
                                disable-output-escaping="yes" />

                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="$table"
                disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

I modified the code now I am using `position()` to find out if an closing `<tr>` or an opening `</tr>` is required.

The whole problem might be summarized to that you can not write single tags in XSLT. And that `disable-output-escaping` is not working.

Resulting HTML should be https://jsfiddle.net/dwetctm6/

For all the Nodes in the group. The order of the nodes in the table does not matter.

Furthermore assume following XML:

> ```
> <bgroup>
>   <NODE1>text</NODE1>
>   <NODE2>text</NODE2>
>   <NODE n-1>text</NODE n-1>
>   <NODE n>text</NODE n>
> </bgroup>
> ```

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, including input, an executable stylesheet, and the expected result - see: [mcve]

Comment: I dont understand why you are wanting all of my data. I want a two-column table. Isnt it clear if you have a look on the code? whats unclear?

Comment: I don't want **all** your data. I want enough code that would enable me to reproduce your problem by nothing more than copy/pasting it into my testing environment. And I need to know what the correct result is, so that I can suggest a way to get it.

Comment: "*you can not write single tags in XSLT.*" No, you can't. Nor do you need to. You just need to approach the problem with a different logic.

Comment: A sample of your input XML is required.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sry for appearing unkind.. I mess around with this problem for now about 6hours..

Comment: You are still being unkind by posting an input that is not well-formed XML, and not including your output in your question. There's an excellent advice in the help section: "**Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague**" . http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, he/she did include the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing nodes into a two-column table is pretty trivial - especially if the order (across-first or down-first) does not matter.

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/bgroup">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="*[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **well-formed** inpout:

**XML**

```
<bgroup>
  <NODE1>A</NODE1>
  <NODE2>B</NODE2>
  <NODE3>C</NODE3>
  <NODE4>D</NODE4>
  <NODE5>E</NODE5>
</bgroup>
```

the result will be:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td/>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. Yes.. It is trivial IF you know this `following-sibling::*[1]` .. I preferred your solution using a for-each instead of the templates..

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few remarks must be made first of all:

1. You must learn how XSLT works: It is a language for templating that, being based on XML, must be composed in an **ordered way**: Every node open must be closed within the same scope. michael.hor257k is right: You shall not open a node within an scope and close it in another different one.
2. Also, there must be said that your input XML does not seem to be properly structured: It should be a repetition of nodes with same names and types. If all the `NODE-n` nodes are functionally or semantically equal, they should have the same name, no problem: You can have several nodes with the same name.

And now, the solution: Asuming your XML is as you have posted it, and since there can't be a templating definition based upon named nodes with different names, I have matched *all the child nodes* of the `bgroup` root node. So, the XSL can be as easy as this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/bgroup">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod 2 =1]"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's important that you realise how, thanks to the **ordered structure** of the XSL language, you can see how the output will be with just a glimpse of the XSL template.